# How to revert Postgres to some time ealier?

Tags: postgresql, recovery

Consider this scenario, I made some update to a running Postgres database, and some bad things happen.

Now I want to rollback the database to 1 hour earlier, what's the process to achieve this?

I was reading [continuous archiving of pg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/continuous-archiving.html), and but didn't find the relevant option for me to specify the rollback time. The most relevant one is `recovery_target_timeline` but I am not sure how it is applied.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to undo a committed transaction. You have to restore a physical (file system level) backup and use point-in-time-recovery to recover (forward) to a point before the problem happened.

Comment: just a correct full backup restore would be good enough. No reason to restore the complete filesystem.

Comment: @ik_zelf I didn't mean a backup of the file system, but a physical backup of the database. I tried to clarify my answer.

Comment: How does one specify that point?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille The question was if it is possible to roll back the database to a state one hour in the past, so the time is known.

Comment: How do you tell PostgreSQL not to recover beyond a known point in time?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille By specifying `recovery_target_time`. See the documentation.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe I am asking about how to perform the PITR, not if it is possible

Comment: No, you were asking how to rollback a database to an hour in the past, which is not possible.

Comment: It used to be called  "roll-forward".  As Laurenz answered: you restore a full backup, then you gather your archived logs and let PostgreSQL replay them up to the instant things went wrong.  It may be a Pain In The Rear, but who burns his behind must sit on the blisters.